# Python: Read in Data from File

Tags: python, file-io, input

I have to read data from a text file from the command line. It is not too difficult to read in each line, but I need a way to separate each part of the line.

The file contains the following in order for several hundred lines:
String (Sometimes more than 1 word)
Integer
String (Sometimes more than 1 word)
Integer

So for example the input could have:

```
Hello 5 Sample String 10
```

The current implementation I have for reading in each line is as follows... how can I modify it to separate it into what I want? I have tried splitting the line, but I always end up getting only one character of the first string this way with no integers or any part of the second string.

```
with open(sys.argv[1],"r") as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

The desired output would be:

```
Hello
5
Sample String
10
```

and so on for each line in the file. There could be thousands of lines in the file. I just need to separate each part so I can work with them separately.

Comment: your question is unclear , whats the problem ? can you add an desire input and output ?

Comment: specify the line format more clearly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program can't magically split lines the way you want. You will need to read in one line at a time and parse it yourself based on the format.

Since there are two integers and an indeterminate number of (what I assume are) space-delimited words, you may be able to use a regular expression to find the integers then use them as delimiters to split up the line.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I did figure out what I was trying to do. I am able to use readline and then access parts of the line.. for example line[12:18] gives me characters 12 through 18 of the line.

Comment: That will definitely work, assuming your lines are in a fixed-width format.

Comment: They are, I should have mentioned that.

Comment: One question I have is.. I am trying to make a adjacency list to represent the data as a graph and I need to make a node for every unique string in the file. Do you have any idea how I should go about this? Or is it worth asking a new question? I tried adding each to an array as I went, but I figure that would be inefficient.

Comment: Please post this as another question. Each topic on SO should be about a single problem.